# Share common templates across groups in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

Using a self-hosted GitLab instance where we need to use common templates across several groups.

Currently we copy and paste templates into a "project-templates" projects within each group. This becomes a maintenance issue when templates are updated.

Is there a better method for managing common templates across multiple groups?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is still a concern for you but while digging around for a solution I found [this article](https://dev.to/anhtm/a-comprehensive-guide-to-creating-your-own-gitlab-ci-template-library-5b3i) that is what I am using to guide my way through the problem.

TL;DR

1. Create a project for storing your template
2. Add your template yaml
3. Reference it in your project `.gitlab-ci.yaml` files with an `include` stanza

```
include:
  - project: 'full/path/to/project'  
    ref: 'master'
    file: '<file_name>.yml'
```

The project path is as you would find it in your URL when look at the project in GitLab.